# How Get HiddenField Value on PageLoad (Code behind)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, hiddenfield

I used Java Script for set Value on Hidden field ,
i want use hidden field value for Data Source on Repeater
but i have Empty Value because i need first run Java Script and Get Value on Page Load.
How it's Possible?
My Javascript Code is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function showPosition(position) {
                //x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
                //"<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
                //console.log("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
                //"<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude);

                var lat = position.coords.latitude;

                document.getElementById('<%= hdfLat.ClientID %>').value = lat;

                var lon = position.coords.longitude;

                document.getElementById('<%= hdfLong.ClientID %>').value = lon; 
            });                 
        } else {
            var error = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
            alert(error);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You *could* do inject script from code behind, then get the value, but if the script takes time to finish, the code could fail. Instead, leave the script on the page and when the script finishes, call a code behind method using `Page Methods`. Search for how `Page Methods` work.

Answer (score 0):

look like you can call your function or make it a self executing function.

getLocation();

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reply,
it's not problem ,i run function on body with onload="getLocation();" and i have value on Hidden Field ,main my problem is i have null value on HiddenFile on pageLoad

Comment: I dont think you can use a hiddenfield since it does not do autopostback. Try a regular textbox with autopostback=true and add onchange event to textbox then hide it with css.